# Navgigation.navigate(param) with PushNotification in react native and react navigation

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-navigation

I want to redirect my user on the page I choose when they click on my push notification. I know how to get parameters from firebase.

Push Notification package : https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification
React navigation : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/

Index.tsx :

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import PushNotification from "react-native-push-notification";
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

PushNotification.configure({
    
    onNotification: function (notification) {
        
        console.log(notification)

        screenToRedirect = notification.data.screen //from firebase key => value

        //here I'd like to do something like this : 

        const navigation = useNavigation(); 
        navigation.navigate(screenToRedirect )

    },
    requestPermissions: Platform.OS === 'ios'
    
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

It tells me:
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. Problem : I can't put the PushNotification.configure inside a component (it is mentioned in the doc).

Comment: If you take the solution from the question and post it as an answer you can mark that answer as accepted and it will benefit both you and the community. You'll get credit, and the question won't appear to have an unaccepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION

I just added my principal menu in the root navigation. So the navigationRef return my principal menu, example :

```
export const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export const MyDrawer = () => {
  return(
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Accueil">
      <Drawer.Screen name="Accueil" component={Home} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Qui sommes-nous ?" component={Who} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Nos Services" component={Services} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Nos Biens" component={Bien} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  )
}

export const Bottom = createBottomTabNavigator();

export const MyBottom = () => {
  return(
    <Bottom.Navigator
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
          let iconName;

          if (route.name === 'Home') {
            iconName = focused
              ? 'home'
              : 'folder';
          } else if (route.name === 'Mon Profil') {
            iconName = focused ? 'alert-circle' : 'aperture-sharp';
          }

          // You can return any component that you like here!
          return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
        },
        tabBarActiveTintColor: 'tomato',
        tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
      })}
    >
      <Bottom.Screen name="Home" component={MyDrawer} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
      <Bottom.Screen name="Mon Profil" component={Profil} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
    </Bottom.Navigator>

  )
}



export const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef()

export function navigate(name, params) {
    if (navigationRef.isReady()) {
      navigationRef.navigate(name, params);
    }
  }


const RootStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function AppMenu() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef} independent={true}>
      <RootStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Accueil">

        // Here, I return My Bottom which is the principal menu that return itself MyDrawer menu
        <RootStack.Screen name="Home2" component={MyBottom} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
      </RootStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

And now My App.tsx return AppMenu.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use hooks outside react components. You can try this solution: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/

Answer (score 2):

**Here's how I solved this problem:**

1- First create a RootNavigation,js file

2- Add the below code in that file

```
import {createNavigationContainerRef} from '@react-navigation/native';

export const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef();

export function navigate(name, params) {
if (navigationRef.isReady()) {
navigationRef.navigate(name, params);
 }
}
```

3- Add navigationRef in navigation container

```
import {navigationRef} from './RootNavigation';

<NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
  <MainStack />
</NavigationContainer>
```

4- Now you can use this ref outside of NavigationContainer as well if you have initialized your push notifications in app.js

```
import * as RootNavigation from './src/navigation/RootNavigation';

***if you are using one signal for push notifications then you can navigate to your screen in setNotificationOpenedHandler method***

  //Method for handling notifications opened
OneSignal.setNotificationOpenedHandler(notification => {
  
  RootNavigation.navigate("your_screen_name");

});
```